# Why same font size show different actual size in different editors?

Tags: macos, fonts, font-size

Environment: Mac OS El Capitan; MBP 2012-Mid 15'.
Same problem on both built-in LCD and external LCDs. I have tried with 3 external monitors. Also same problem on another MBP with Retina internal LCD. Also, same problem occurs no matter the resolution is scaled, not scaled, or HiDPI.

As the screenshot shows, **same font name + same font size + same text + same screen** has different visual width in different text editors. I have tried to tune one of the font size to be like 14.1/13.9/etc, but not works, the text is either too small/narrow or too big/wide; what's more, some editors cannot use fraction font size.

Q1: How to show exactly same visual size for same font size?

Q2: Looks like there are two font rendering engines in the OS? If yes, how to specify which one to use for specified app or for all apps?

Thanks a lot.

[image]